# Chunking Files in C# .Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-5, chunks

I have large video files I'm trying to break down into chunks and reassemble on the server side. I've mostly been following the suggestions in [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-large-files-to-mvc-webapi-using-partitioning/), but I'm having some issues.

In the code that's bundling up the chunks and sending them across the wire, I have this code:

```
     using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
        {
            var requestUri = ApiHelper.GetUrl("api/uploadFile");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(requestUri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Constants.ApiKeyHeaderName, Constants.RoadLivesApiAppKey);

            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
                fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new
                    ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
                };
                content.Add(fileContent);

                try
                {
                    var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
                    rslt = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    rslt = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

On the server side, I'm trying to get that content back out as a byte array so I can reassemble the file when everything is uploaded. The linked article suggests using `Request.Files`, which doesn't exist in .NET 5. I've tried utilizing `Request.Form.Files`, but the whole `Request.Form` appears empty.

Are there any suggestions for how I can get the `ByteArrayContent` from the Request object? The `Request.ContentLength` matches what I expect, but I'm not sure where I can get that data from.

I've tried to get the `ByteArrayContent` from the `Request.Body` per the options below but it's not working as expected.

```
        byte[] bodByteArray;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Request.BodyReader.CopyToAsync(ms);
        //Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
        bodByteArray = ms.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is much simpler. Here's an example:
Server:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Example.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    public class UploadController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task PostAsync(
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            byte[] bytes;

            // To get bytes, use this code (await is required, you missed it)
            // But I recommend working with Stream in order not to load the server's RAM.
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await Request.BodyReader.CopyToAsync(memoryStream, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            // use bytes here
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Example.Apis
{
    public partial class ExampleApi
    {
        public async Task UploadAsync(
            string path,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();

            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
                HttpMethod.Post,
                new Uri("https://localhost:5001/api/v1/upload"))
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(path)),
            };
            
            using var response = await client.SendAsync(
                request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. In addition to examples, I advise you to learn about Streams as the correct way to work with large files.